# Java - Extract html information from string

Tags: java, html, string, tags, extract

All of the guides out there tell me on how to remove the HTML tags from the text to extract the text between them.  What I am after is the extraction of the data that is within the HTML tags.

e.g.

If i have a string:

```
 "<FONT SIZE="5">Hello World</FONT>"
```

I want to get the font size information to update other variables. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) several times for this purpose. It's a lenient HTML parser. Beware trying to parse it as "standard" XML as XML-parsing is strict by nature and will fail if the page does not conform to XML markup specs (which few HTML pages do).

Comment: Look at the jsoup homepage under [Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/). Plenty of examples. Like [this](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

Answer (score 1):

You go about this by using one of the available Java libraries for HTML parsing, like [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup).

Comment: Or HtmlParser ( http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/ ), or libraries used in HtmlUnit.

Comment: Or "jsoup" [link](http://jsoup.org) [link](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [jerichoHTML](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) wich enables you to search for HTML tags as well as their attributes or you build some DOM on you own.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing
If you parse the HTML you should be able to extract the values from the DOM tree.

Comment: -1 very bad idea. Few HTML pages conform closely enough to XML to be parse-able by an XML parser. HTML != XML. And since browsers are lenient, even pages developed in XHTML tends to be "sloppy".